# Reference for GCD domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, reference-request, gcd-and-lcm

I'm looking for some good references (book or document) about GCD domains and properties of them. I've googled but I have not find any. Suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: GCD means what?

Comment: [greatest common divisor domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend Pete L. Clark's [notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral2015.pdf) on commutative algebra. Chapter $15$ has many interesting properties of GCD-domains.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, appreciated!